# vbs open, loop through message, close application

Tags: vbscript

I have solved a few of these issues with the code below. The part where I'm getting stuck is looping back through the message popup. If the answer is Yes, I want it to loop back to the top; if the answer is No, I want it to exit the loop and close the program; if the message box times out, I want it to exit the loop and close the program as well. Please see my code below. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
Dim PromptTime, DelayTime, StrAppPath, AppExec, MsgTxt, intAnswer, intRet

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

PromptTime = 5
DelayTime = 4
StrAppPath = "C:Windows\"
AppExec = "Notepad.exe"
MsgTxt = "Are you still using Notepad?"
intMsgTimeout = 5
Set WshShell= CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run chr(34) & StrAppPath & AppExec & chr(34), 1, "False"
Do
WScript.Sleep (1000 * 1 * PromptTime)
'intAnswer = MsgTxt(MsgTxt, vbYesNo, "Please select Yes or No")
intResult = WshShell.Popup(MsgTxt, intMsgTimeout, "Warning!", vbYesNo)

Select Case WshShell
Case vbYes
If intResult = vbYes Then Do

Case vbNo
If intResult = vbNo Then Exit Do

'Case Else
If intResult = Else Then Exit Do

End Select
Loop

taskKill = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & taskKill & "\root\cimv2")

Set processlistFull= objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where name = 'Notepad.exe'")

For Each killPro In processlistFull
killPro.Terminate()
Next

Set objShell = Nothing
Set objWmi = Nothing
Set objQResult = Nothing
```

Comment: *I have solved a few of these issues with the code below* – if so, what's your question exactly?

Comment: I think you should clean up your code to begin with. I see thing like `If intResult = vbYes Then Do` which make no sense to me. Make sure you close each `If`with an `End if`

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a method of doing this through 'Loop While' and removing the Select Case:

```
Do
WScript.Sleep (1000 * 1 * PromptTime)
Loop While WshShell.Popup("Are you still using Syteline?", 5, "Please select yes or no", vbYesNo) = vbYes
```